# Import errors when moving from Python 3.6 to 3.7+, root-directory no longer legal from root_dir import

Tags: python, python-import

I've inherited code that gets the following

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named *this_dir*

when run on Python 3.7 or 3.8, but runs fine on Python 3.6.

*this_dir* contains:

- `__init__.py` -- an empty file
- and `mymain.py` -- a file that I want to run from the *this_dir* -- it has a number of imports of the form, `from this_dir import foo`
- several files like `foo.py` that are imported in `mymain.py`

To run:

```
python3.x mymain.py -p1 -p2 ...
```

Additionally, there is a *completely independent module* in a parallel directory that also has

```
from this_dir import far
```

Now, I would ignore this all except I want to use a feature introduced in Python 3.7.

Is there a way to define things in `__init__.py` to fix this?

Comment: What role does the completely independent module in a parallel directory play in this question?

Comment: Good question @mkrieger1, and thanks, it occurs to me that this may be pointing at the problem.  These have been pip installed so that they can import code from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the problem is that the code modules have been *pip install*ed in python3.6 making *this_dir* globally accessible in 3.6, but not in 3.7.
This seems a categorically poor way of doing this to me, but ...
I'm going to read up on name resolution because I'm surprised this is legal, but also to make sure there are no gotta's.  If any of the more knowledge care to comment on the wisdom of developing against an installed module while it is installed I'm all ears.  The cross dependency is clearly a problem.
What you get when EEs are allowed to write code unsupervised.

Comment: I regularly develop sibling projects in sandboxes that I have each installed using `pip install -e .`, so that the projects see their dependencies the same way they will when published to PyPI and installed using a regular pip install. I think all you need to be mindful of, is that if you have multiple python versions, they each have an environment that includes everything you need to run your project.